# Find address using pointer and offset C#

Tags: c#, memory, pointers, offset

I made a lot of research on memory reading and I reached here. I got the pointer and offset values, by adding an address manually and choosing "Pointer" on Cheat Engine I can get the address. But my question is how can I do this on C#?

**Pointer:** "client.dll"+0065F38

**Offset:** E4

This two values return the address in Cheat Engine, I want to know how can I make it in C#.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are actually trying to do. Do what in C#? Add an offset to an address? Something else?

Comment: What? How can you do do what in C#? Adding a known offset to a know pointer value? You just add them together

Comment: @EdS: Cheat Engine is simply a RAM hex editor.  It is almost exclusively used in single player games because it is really obvious in what it does and even the most pathetic anti-cheat systems will detect it instantly.  I would suggest you relax a bit.

Comment: I have no idea what you're even trying to do.

Comment: @YYY: I know what it is, thanks. Contrary to your claim, it's used in many games that have online modes and little to no cheat detection.  I played DII which was plagued by this nonsense.  If the OP wants to do it then fine, but I won't put information here to help others who want to mess with my gameplay experience.  Anyway, the question is unclear at best and I see no effort by the OP.

Comment: @EdS I fail to see how its use in a game that is well over a decade old constitutes 'many games'.  Cheat Engine is picked up instantly by every major anti-cheat program out there.  I have had to secure against its use myself.  Some look for it specifically.  Anyway I will not reply any more to you because you are letting your preconceptions get the best of you, hope you didn't let this question ruin your day.

Comment: @YYY: That was an example, and people play DII to this day if you weren't aware.  Not sure what "preconceptions" you are referring to, but not all games are AAA titles and many are still susceptible to this sort of hack.  I suppose there is enough information available on client-side hacks out there anyway as to render the point moot, but I don't like contributing if I can avoid it.  Anyway, it's irrelevant as this is a poor quality question and will be closed soon enough.  Can't imagine that this would "ruin my day", but thanks all the same.

Comment: Guys, I just want to turn a "pointer" + "offset" value into "address" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't go into too much detail, but `"client.dll"+0065F38` won't help you too much.
Luckily for you, I wrote a [tutorial of how to write a trainer](http://haxordotnet.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/how-to-build-trainer-to-game-and-magic.html) in C#.

Comment: Thanks, you were the only one who really answered my question.

Comment: @MarkSegal The download links in your tutorial are broken, can you fix them please?